# Change the URL of save button in the admin grid

Tags: grid, magento-2.2.5, save

In Magento 2.2.5, How to change the URL of save button in the admin grid.

Note: I am not creating grid through ui_component, I am creating grid using layout.

Reference: [Ref 1](https://www.aurigait.com/blog/magento-2-admin-grid/) [Ref 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

Comment: What you want to change  
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton</item>?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra It is not Ui component Grid

Comment: Okay so in layout what you want change? means which url url are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the save button URL by overriding the **getSaveUrl()** function.

Navigate to

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit.php

add the following function in this file

```
public function getSaveUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('module/controller/action');
}
```

Comment: Its working fine.